# Image banner above Twitter bootstrap header

Tags: html, css, image, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to have a banner above my bootstrap page. My code is below

HTML

```
<div class="masthead">
  <img src="images/gov-header.jpg"/>
</div>
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">MST</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="content.html">Divisions</a></li>
        <li><a href="#projects">Projects</a></li>
        <li><a href="#faqs">FAQs</a></li>
        <li><a href="#resources">Resources</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact Us</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div>
```

CSS

```
.masthead img{
  width:100%;
}
```

Comment: Make it a background instead and set the height of masthead to the height of the image

Comment: Use <div class="col-xs-12 >your image</div>and put masthead in same div after image

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Its better as a background.

```
.masthead{
    height://height of bg;
    background-image:url("../images/gov-header.jpg");
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

Hope this gives you some ideas. You can modify this depending on if you want to fill the whole width or just container length.

**Update**
You have to change

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
```

to

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
```

**See the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/NK6nh/3/**

Comment: still appears under the header not really below it.

Comment: Friends don't let friends skip leg day.